# Bounded metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose that $(X, d)$ is a metric space, $A\subseteq X$. Show that $A$ is bounded if and only if there is some constant $\Delta$ such that $d(a,a')\leq \Delta$ for all $a, a' \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $A$ is contained in the ball $B(b,r)=\{ x\in X; d(b,x)<r\}$, then use the triangle
inequality to determine $\Delta$. If $d(a,a')\leq \Delta$, show that $A\subseteq B(a_0,\Delta)$ where $a_0 \in A$ is arbitrary.